What factors and forces affect the velocity of volcanic emissions in the atmosphere?
Niche question for a niche subfield of Physics. While exploring the Sulfur Dioxide ($SO_2$) data from the Geostationary Environment Monitoring Spectrometer (GEMS), I noticed that during the moment eruption and for a few hours thereafter, volcanic emissions tend to travel faster than the clouds travelling parallel (and, I'm assuming, affected by the same weather phenomenon) to the said emissions.
I've also observed that the said $SO_2$, aside from "thinning out" and losing concentration over time, tend to lose velocity as well, as they now tend to travel with the same speed and direction to clouds travelling in parallel.
Which leads me to asking this:
What forces affect the velocity of volcanic emissions in the atmosphere?
Any explanation, whether math heavy or not, is appreciated. In fact, if anyone can refer to a research paper tackling this very specific question, I'd be a very happy person.

Probably the emissions are at a higher altitude than the clouds and wind speeds are higher there.  A comment rather than an answer because I don't currently have evidence for this hypothesis.
